# melt pandas dataframe multiple columns into 2

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns: `ID_col B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3`

I want to create a dataframe with the structure:

```
    ID_col    B          C
    ID_1      B1_value   C1_value
    ID_2      B2_value   C2_value
```

I can create columns `ID_col` and `B` like this:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID_col', ], value_vars=keys)
# keys are the list of B1, B2 so on column names
```

But I can't add `C` column

Comment: Your input is unclear, please provide a full example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) :

```
(
    pd.wide_to_long(df, ["B", "C"], i="ID_col", j="temp_col")
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values(by="ID_col", ignore_index=True)
)
```

##### # Ouptut :

```
  ID_col   B   C
0   ID01   1   4
1   ID01   7   5
2   ID01  10   6
3   ID02   2   3
4   ID02   8  11
5   ID02   9  12
```

And with a chained (`.groupby("ID_col", as_index=False).agg(list)`) at the end :

```
ID_col           B            C
0   ID01  [1, 7, 10]    [4, 5, 6]
1   ID02   [2, 8, 9]  [3, 11, 12]
```

*Used input :*

```
print(df)
  ID_col  B1  B2  B3  C1  C2  C3
0   ID01   1   7  10   4   5   6
1   ID02   2   8   9   3  11  12
```